# Ubuntu: Accidentally changed root user to nonexistent shell

Tags: ubuntu, shell, user-accounts, root, chsh

I tried to change my user's shell, but used "sudo chsh", and changed the root shell to "bash" instead of "/bin/bash". Now when I try to change it I get "chsh: PAM authentication failed" and it seems like other things aren't working, either.

```
~$ sudo su
Cannot execute bash: No such file or directory
```

This happens with recovery mode, too. What do I do to change it to something usable?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are able to login using your regular user, just change the root users shell directly:

```
sudo gedit /etc/passwd
```

Find the line for you root user, usually the first one, and change the last part from

```
...:bash
```

to

```
...:/bin/bash
```

And you should be good to go.

(NB: Replace gedit with whatever editor you fancy.)

Answer (score 6):

Use the Ubuntu install disk to boot the live session.

Mount the root ('/') partition on the harddisk (make sure it's writable).

edit '[HD mount point]/etc/passwd' (eg /media/sda1/etc/passwd),

root should be the first line, just correct the login shell which will be the last entry on the line.

Unmount harddisk.  Remove CD.  Reboot

Comment: This is "if you can't log in as your regular user"

Answer (score 2):

I played with this once ages ago:

```
cd /bin ; sudo su
```

What's happening is without a / in front the shell is being interpreted as a relative path. Oh gee if we are in /bin it resolves correctly.

If you get really stuck; the rescue CD is the long way around. The boot option init=/bin/sh gives you a root shell immediately. The cursor just blinks at you with no prompt but you have a root shell. Do

```
set -i
# mount / -o remmount,rw
# vi /etc/passwd
<fix it>
# mount / -o remount,ro
# reboot -f
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, as a short-term work-around, you can use the "-s" switch on the su command to specify a shell.  For example:

```
su -s /bin/bash
```

would start your su session with the /bin/bash shell.  Same goes for sudo su -s /bin/bash (or whatever shell you'd like) @Bjarke Freund-Hansen's answer is the permanent fix.

Comment: I've just found out yesterday this doesn't work. If the current shell for the target account isn't in /etc/shells, su ignores -s unless the caller is already root.

Comment: Did you try putting sudo in front of the su like the original question does?